# Mutex Behavior when we copy one structure to another

Tags: c, mutex

I want to know what happens when I copy one structure to another and that structure contains a mutex element. The structure is:

```
typedef struct p_copy {
    int id;
    int salary;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} p_copy_t;
```

Say, I have **p_copy_t p1** with values assigned to all members and have another structure **p_copy_t p2** (initialized to 0). when I do, p2=p1, does the mutex address get copied from p1 to p2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy one `struct` to another via the assignment operator, you get a copy of the *object representation*.  In other words, the effect on the left-hand operand is the same as that of

```
memcpy(&p2, &p1, sizeof(p_copy_t));
```

, supposing that `p1` and `p2` are indeed distinct.  The details of `pthread_mutex_t` are not documented, but supposing that it is a `struct` (and not, for instance, a pointer to one instead), you get a copy of that struct's contents, not of its address.

As far as I am aware, the result of operating on such a copied mutex object with any of the `pthread_mutex_*()` functions is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When copying from one structure it is safer to use. If the structure contains pointer then only the address is copied to destination.

```
Example:

memcpy(&p2, &p1, sizeof(p1));
```

That's being said, copying the pthread_mutex depends on how the structure is defined.

You can always use a pointer to get the address of the mutex defined and no need to copy to another structure and it is also safer.

Comment: C supports `struct` assignment, and there's no particular reason to avoid it if it provides the semantics you want.  In particular, there is no reason whatever to prefer `memcpy()`, as it provides *the same* semantics as ordinary assignment.